# Unable to send data to other page on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi I am developing one asp.net javascript application in sharepoint. There are 2 pages. First page is default.aspx. I have one gridview with edit button. Whenever i click on edit button i want to redirect to addnewitem.aspx page. Whenever i click on edit i want to send current row data in querystring to addnewitem.aspx. I am trying as below. But my page is refreshing and not gettingredirecting to addnewitem.aspx

Below is my gridview code. I am getting data.

```
function readAll() {
    var clientContext;
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Requisition');
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit></RowLimit>10</View>');
    var items = oList.getItems(query);
    clientContext.load(oList);
    clientContext.load(items);
    var table = $("#addtable");
    var innerHtml = "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>PrimarySkills</th><th>SecondarySkills</th><th>Vacanies</th><th>JobSummary</th><th>JobDescription</th><th>Experience_x0028_Yrs_x0029_</th><th>Qualification</th><th>m</th><th>Customer</th><th>RecievedDate</th><th>TargetDate</th><th>Comments1</th><th>Division</th><th>Actions</th></tr>";
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        var itemInfo = '';
        var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
           var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
           innerHtml += "<tr><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('ID') + "</td><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('Title') + "</td><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('PrimarySkills') + "</td><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('SecondarySkills') +"</td><td scope='col'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-cons blue' id='Edit'>Edit</button></td></tr>";

        }
        table.html(innerHtml);
   }),
   Function.createDelegate(this, fail)
   );
   function success() {
       $("#dvMessage").text("Operation Completed Successfully");
   }

   function fail() {
       $("#dvMessage").text("Operation failed  " + arguments[1].get_message());
   }
}
```

In the above code my Edit button reloads. I wanted to redirect to other page. This is not happening. document.location.href = url; is this is the correct way to redirect?

This is my edit button code.

```
$('#addtable td:nth-child(4)').bind('click', function () {
    alert("Clicked");
    var Title = $(this).closest("tr").children().eq(0).html();
    var PrimarySkills = $(this).closest("tr").children().eq(1).html();
    var SecondarySkills = $(this).closest("tr").children().eq(2).html();

    var url = 'http://sites/APPSTEST/JobRequisitionApp/Pages/AddNewItem.aspx?Title=' + encodeURIComponent(Title) + 'PrimarySkills=' + encodeURIComponent(PrimarySkills) + 'SecondarySkills=' + encodeURIComponent(SecondarySkills);
    document.location.href = url;
});
```

Can someone guide me to achieve this? Thank you all.

Comment: window.location is the documented way, but document.location.href should work even though it is supposed to be read-only

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are clicking the `button` on the row, but your bind/handler is against the `td`

```
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-cons blue' id='Edit'>Edit</button>
```

by default a button without a type is the same as `<button type='submit'..` so every time you click the button, it submits your form (which all SharePoint pages contain) thus you get the postback/refresh.

One simple option is to remove the `<button>` part of your html build and replace with some plain text, ie `<td>edit</td>` this should then trigger your bind.  However, this is not very neat.

Change the button to a button

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-cons blue' id='Edit'>Edit</button>
```

and change the handler to trigger on the button:

```
$('#addtable td:nth-child(5) button').bind(
```

**NB:** the nth-child should be 5 as the 5th column is the one with the button

you could also `return false` from the handler after changing it to trigger on the button, but the change to `type=button` handles this and stops it from submitting.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your response. Now I am unable to click edit button. nothing happened.

Comment: HI Niranjan, can you share what changes you have made to solve the issue?

Comment: Your `n-child` is not selecting the correct column, change it to `$('#addtable td:nth-child(5) button')` or just remove the nth-child part: `$("#addtable td button")` assuming you'll only have one button per row.

Comment: Apologies for not spotting this earlier, but the html generation is quite hard to read like that.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. i changed as below. I wrote onclick='getValues()'and inside this i write above code. But problem is that  var Title = $(this).closest("tr").children().eq(0).html(); is not fetching required values. '

Comment: I just hardcoded values and i am redirecting to other page. My url is "http://sites/APPSTEST/JobRequisitionApp/Pages/AddNewItem.aspx?Title=dfdPrimarySkills=fdfdSecondarySkills=dfdf". I am able to redirect to that page also but i am not able to fetch values in that page. Any idea on this? Thank you